# Issue with binding class to gridview in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, binding

I'm trying to bind an observablecollection of a custom class to a simple gridview.

This is the gridview template:

```
<ListView Name="TestGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=testlist}">
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AlertType}" Header="Alert" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Target}" Header="Target" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message}" Header="Message" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView>
```

This is the code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<TestClass> testlist {get; set;}

public MainWindow()
 {
        InitializeComponent();

        testlist = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
        testlist.Add(new TestClass("Type1","Target1","Message1"));
        testlist.Add(new TestClass("Type2", "Target2", "Message2"));
 }

public class TestClass
{
    public string AlertType { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public TestClass(string a, string t, string m)
    {
        AlertType = a;
        Target = t;
        Message = m;
    }
}
```

Now I've been following exactly the samples I could find on the internet. Unfortunately the only result I get in my gridview is a unique line displaying the follwoing message: **"System.Windows.Controls.Columns.Count:3"**

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your xaml and code behind as:

```
          <ListView Name="TestGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=testlist}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AlertType}" Header="Alert" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Target}" Header="Target" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message}" Header="Message" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

code behind

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    testlist = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
    testlist.Add(new TestClass("Type1","Target1","Message1"));
    testlist.Add(new TestClass("Type2", "Target2", "Message2"));
    DataContext = this;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this is way better, since I can now see the correct headers. However, the two occurences are not displayed, only the headers

Comment: have you set the DataContext as shown in the answer? if yes.. are you getting any binding errors in output window when you launch your window?

Comment: I did set the DataContext, and I do not get any binding errors when running the window.

Comment: Okay now it's working finally. I restarted the project and it's ok now. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the View property on the ListView:

```
<ListView Name="TestGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=testlist}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AlertType}" Header="Alert" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Target}" Header="Target" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message}" Header="Message" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>    
</ListView>
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a very trivial error. Now that it is corrected, I can see the headers, but the two occurences are not displayed

Comment: Nice. That fixes it. Xaml is not showing any error when doin it without the View. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating viewModel for the window and set it as datacontext of the window. 
update your code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ExampleViewModel m_ViewModel;      
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_ViewModel = new ExampleViewModel();
        DataContext = m_ViewModel;
    }
}


public class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TestClass> m_testlist;
    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        m_testlist = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
        m_testlist.Add(new TestClass("Type1", "Target1", "Message1"));
        m_testlist.Add(new TestClass("Type2", "Target2", "Message2"));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TestClass> testlist
    {
        get
        {
            return m_testlist;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_testlist != value)
            {
                m_testlist = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("testlist");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string AlertType { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public TestClass(string a, string t, string m)
    {
        AlertType = a;
        Target = t;
        Message = m;
    }
}
```